# Nim compiler fails with "Requested command not found: gcc.exe"

Tags: gcc, nim-lang

I tried to launch first program in nim. I downloaded Windows installer from the official site and did the installation with all possible components. But when I try to run the program I get the message:

```
"unhandled exception: Requested command not found: 'gcc.exe -c -w -IC:nimlib -o 
 c:nimworknimcacheaa.o c:nimworknimcacheaa.c'. OS error: [OSError] > 
 Process terminated with exit code 1"
```

is it possible to fix this situation?

Comment: make sure gcc.exe is included in your path environment.

Answer (score 7):

From Nim's [website](http://nim-lang.org/download.html):

Note: The Nim compiler requires a C compiler to compile software. On Windows we recommend that you use [Mingw-w64](http://mingw-w64.org/doku.php). GCC is recommended on Linux and Clang on Mac.

Make sure to add the gcc binaries to your [PATH](https://superuser.com/questions/284342/what-are-path-and-other-environment-variables-and-how-can-i-set-or-use-them).

Answer (score -1):

download nim lag and exract the file and paste it in your directory lib